# exit code -1073741571 (0xC0000FD) with tensorflow in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Description**

I implemented a model with tensorflow via PyCharm on Windows 7. This implemented model worked well. After i got some problems i have to install a new OS (Windows 10). I also installed something that i used to run the model such as PyCharm, Anaconda, Git etc. Likewise in Anaconda i installed python, tensorflow, SimpleITK.

**Problem**

When i run the model on a new environment, i got a error below:

Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

**Solved**

I created a new virtual environment on Anaconda that changed the versions of both python and tensorflow. The python is 3.6 to 3.5 and the tensorflow is 1.9 to 1.3. After that it works fine.

Comment: That's a stack-overflow :-).  Whichever program gives that error should be investigated.  Does python run from the command-line?

Comment: @cdarke I will update this question more detail. Anyway i got this error from the command line in PyCharm

Comment: OK, what about cmd.exe?  Its just that you need to tie it down to a particular program or package.  You probably won't be able to fix it yourself, but at least you would know who to complain to.

Comment: @cdark Ok, I understand what you said. Anyway during several weeks I got too much problems for others. I concentrated on that all time and i did not search for this enough. I just wish that someone tell me this problem as soon as possible. And i am going to update this question gradually.

Comment: The error is often caused by recursion.  Python guards against that but one of the packages written in C could be causing it.  In Windows stack limits are set at compile time, so it could just be an incorrect compiler flag instead.  You have so many packages installed that could be causing it you need to break it down methodically.